# Need help creating flash animation with clickable buttons at the end

Tags: flash, button, action

Very inexperienced with Flash, but I hope this is simple enough for someone to walk me through.

I'm ultimately trying to create a flash page for an html website that has a brief five-second animation during which 3 buttons fade in (buttons then become clickable after the animation is over).

The animation part is done.  Right now, I am trying to get my movie to stop and hold on the last frame, where I want to add the 3 buttons that the user can click on to take them to one 3 different html pages of my website.

All instructions that I've found online have said to create a new layer for actions, insert a keyframe on the last frame of the movie, and add stop(); in the actionscript window.  However, when I have the keyframe selected, my actionscript window says "current selection cannot have actions applied to it".

Any ideas?  I definitely don't have any objects selected, just the keyframe.

Below here is a link to an image, if that helps.  You can see that I have the frame (a keyframe) that I want to insert a "stop" action selected in the Actions layer.  This is the first frame in which the buttons exist, and from what I can tell, I need the clip to stop on the first frame of my buttons, after my animation is over.  (Still figuring out how to get the buttons to work, but will address that later...)

Let me know that I'm approaching this correctly, and what's going wrong!

http://www.footprintsfamilyphoto.com/wp-content/themes/Footprints/images/flash_as3issue.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

1. Move the actions layer to the absolute top.
2. Lock all other layers. I have a sneaking suspicion you do have something other than the frame selected, despite what your screenshot shows.
3. Hit Edit>Deselect All to ensure nothing is selected.

If you still have problems, let me know.

-Matt

Comment: Thanks so much for the response - did all of the above and still no luck :(  Is there something really fundamental that I'm not doing before trying to apply an action?  There aren't any other actions in this file so far.

updated screen shot:  http://www.footprintsfamilyphoto.com/wp-content/themes/Footprints/images/flash_as3issue.jpg

http://www.footprintsfamilyphoto.com/wp-content/themes/Footprints/images/flash_as3issue2.jpg

Comment: Boy, it's a real puzzler then.

Your next action should be trying to squash the bug in as many ways as possible.

My suggestions?

1. Make a new layer and try it out.
2. Try moving the frame around the layer, then selecting it.
3. Add the stop action to one of your tweened layers.

Failing that, I'm open to taking a quick look at the FLA myself and fixing it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice and your offer!  Not sure how/why this worked out, I opened a new flash file, added a couple of test actions to keyframes in that file (which worked fine), closed it without saving, came back to my original file, and suddenly it was allowing me to add action script to the keyframe that I wanted.  I swear I didn't do anything differently, but, given my lack of experience with the program I'll have to chalk it up to something I was overlooking...  working for the moment though so I'll run with it!  Thanks again!